# Java web CMS & HTML presentation, templating

Tags: java, html, content-management-system, alfresco, atompub

I'm looking for a content management system in java with good support for html content presentation in sense of web presentations, NOT document management or enterprise content management

I'm interested in templating html pages in categories/filesystem within the cms. Most CMS I know are corporate systems like Alfresco, Nuxeo, Exo and I don't even know if these have support for web page presentation outside the Portal behind them. I just know that Magnolia does.

---

The second requirement is managing the CMS via API. Not manual editing. I highly doubt that there is a CMS implementing Atom publishing protocol, that's why I need a CMS with API for CRUD content so that I could implement AtomPub server by myself.

Comment: Ad the second requirement: atomsite fully supports Atom and can be used as a CMS. Maybe it would suit your needs, but it is .NET, not Java. http://atomsite.net/

Comment: Thanks Marek, but I need to stick with Java solution. DotCMS seems fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the API side of your question, I'd recommend you pick a CMS that supports [CMIS](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/cmis-spec-v1.0.html), Content Management Interoperability Services, which is a new standard from OASIS.

CMIS supports both web services, and AtomPub, the latter being likely the one you'd want. The [What is CMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/project/cmis.html) page from [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/) is probably a good starting point (Chemistry is an open source project providing clients and server bindings for CMIS)

Answer (score 3):

[DotCMS](http://www.dotcms.org/products/tech-brief/) supports templating, Surf & Edit and Atom feeds

Comment: DotCMS seems OK, especially because it is built on Liferay portal (as they say), but there is extreme lack of documentation. Though they don't support AtomPub protocol there is WebDav support which might be enough for the type of publishing I need. Thank you ktaylorjohn

Answer (score 1):

[Walrus CMS](http://walrus.lt) uses [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) as a templating engine and exports data via RSS and Atom